I am facing this ParseError at [row,col]:[18,57] ..Anyone can explain please?

Facing the ParseError at [row,col]:[18,57] in my project so if any one have a solution please reply.

2.Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:context=".Leave">
   
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
   
           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="70dp"
               android:background="#701198">
   
               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/icon_id"
                   android:layout_width="20dp"
                   android:layout_height="15dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/sym" />
   
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_apply"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                   android:text="Apply Leave"
                   android:textColor="@color/white" />
           </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
       </LinearLayout>
   
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txt_leaveday"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
               android:text="Leave Type"
               android:textColor="@color/black" />
   
           <Spinner
               android:id="@+id/leave_spinner"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
   
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txt_days"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
               android:text="Days"
               android:textColor="@color/black" />
   
           <Spinner
               android:id="@+id/Days_spinner"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
   
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:weightSum="2">
   
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_fromdate"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                   android:text="From Date" />
   
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_todate"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
                   android:text="To Date" />
           </LinearLayout>
   
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
               android:weightSum="2">
   
               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_weight="1">
   
                   <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/frm_date"
                       android:layout_width="18dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:hint="Enter from  date"
                       android:textSize="10sp" />
   
                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/date_click1"
                       android:layout_width="15dp"
                       android:layout_height="20dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:src="@drawable/attd" />
               </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_weight="1">
   
                   <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/to_date"
                       android:layout_width="18dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:hint="Enter to  date"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                       android:textSize="10sp" />
   
                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/date_click2"
                       android:layout_width="15dp"
                       android:layout_height="20dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:src="@drawable/attd" />
               </LinearLayout>
   
           </LinearLayout>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txt_des"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Descriptipon"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
               android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />
   
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/edit_text"
               android:layout_width="350dp"
               android:layout_height="140dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
               android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
               android:gravity="top"/>
       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>


Try removing or changing this line android:background="#701198"

thank you so much. I have  an errors in my another class so it shows errors but now i cleared.
